# C# pattern matching with base class and generic type

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I have this piece of code that checks if an object is of type `Sequence<T>` which works as intended for objects of Type `Task`.

```
public class Sequence<T> {}

public class Task : Sequence<Task> {}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var task = new Task();
                
        // These two are equivalent
        Console.WriteLine(IsSequence(task));
        Console.WriteLine(task is Sequence<Task>); 
    }
    
    public static bool IsSequence<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    {
        return entity is Sequence<TEntity>;
    }
}
```

Now, however, I have a new requirement where these other types `Tool` and `Assembly` should also match, and I am pretty new to the pattern matching in C#, so not sure how to achieve it.

```
public class Sequence<T> {}

public abstract class Item : Sequence<Item> {}

public class Task : Sequence<Task> {}

public class Tool : Item {}

public class Assembly : Item {}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ta = new Tool();
        var tt = new Assembly();
        var task = new Task();
                
        Console.WriteLine(IsSequence(ta));
        Console.WriteLine(IsSequence(tt));
        Console.WriteLine(IsSequence(task));
        
        // What I am posting here is an oversimplification of the real scenario
        // This code for checking if something is a Sequence or not is 
        // handled by a core class with shared functionality that can't know or use the 
        // proper typed overload required.
        // 
        // So doing this is not an option:
        //
        // Console.WriteLine(IsSequence<Item>(ta));
        
        // This is how the output should be
        Console.WriteLine(ta is Sequence<Item>);
        Console.WriteLine(tt is Sequence<Item>);
        Console.WriteLine(task is Sequence<Task>);
    }
    
    public static bool IsSequence<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    {
        // How to rewrite (if possible) this pattern matching so that Task, Tool and Assembly match?
        // So basically I want to know if either TEntity or some of the base types is Sequence<base>
        return entity is Sequence<TEntity>;
    }
}
```

I know that the way it is currently written, it won't match since `Tool`/`Assembly` are not `Sequence<Tool>`/`Sequence<Assembly>`, so I need a way to rewrite the pattern matching to check if it's `Sequence<Item>`.

Here is a [C# Online Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v91p2h) with this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you wrote your function won't work because `Tool` is not a `Sequence<Tool>`, it's a `Sequence<Item>`.

There are many, many ways to write your function if you choose to keep it, for whatever reason, but I'll give you two ways.

First, you can write it to receive an `object` argument then use `is Sequence<T>` inside to figure out if it's a sequence of something. The problem with this is that you need to provide the type argument every time, there's no inference here.

Second, you can write it like this:

```
    public static bool IsSequence<TEntity>(Sequence<TEntity> entity) => true;
    public static bool IsSequence(object obj) => false;
```

In this case there's no need to provide the type argument, just call it with your object and it will return the correct value. And since it relies on compile-time overload resolution, it's very efficient at runtime. Plus it should look familiar to any C++ programmer!

As a third option, extract an interface `ISequence` from your `Sequence<T>` class and then simply test with `is ISequence` with no type argument, since you don't seem to care about it in the test.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation :) I know that's the reason it doesn't work, but need to find a way to rewrite the `is` so that it eventually does.
Could you post an example of the "first" option? 
The second one is not a viable solution in my scenario unfortunately (have edited my answer to clarify more this point)
I was thinking that third option might be the only that could work, but was trying to see if I could get away without using a marker interface.

Comment: `public static bool IsSequence<TEntity>(object obj) => obj is Sequence<TEntity>` and you call it like `IsSequence<Item>(new Tool())`. You're going deep into an XY problem here though with these aribtrary "not a viable solution" and "didn't feel like it", this is absolutely not the way to use C#.

Comment: You are totally right, sorry about that. I think I might have misunderstood your second alternative, let me check it out.

Comment: Didn't manage to fit it in, but will go for the third approach instead. Thanks again.